# Is active class in navbar boostrap changing padding?

Tags: css, class, navbar

It seems to be adding padding only when hovering over it, which makes it look quite silly.

I would like to achieve full fill when active is added - just like when hovering over it.

```
.nav li {
    border-right: 1px dashed grey;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.nav > li:hover, .nav > li:active, .nav > li:focus {
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/JonnyDoe11/g2jw1zp2/)

StackOverflow does not allow me to comment on the answer. So I put it here:

Yes the first anser is right but I want the `li` to be in a better distance one to another. That is why the padding is there.

Comment: If i have understand, you want the active "li" have full fill colored. You just add to your css: .nav li.active{  padding: 0;} https://jsfiddle.net/g2jw1zp2/2/ If you want to mantain the same padding as the other li elements, just add background color to active classes: .nav li.active{ background-color: #E7E7E7; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. The padding remains same on both, the `<li>` and `<a>` elements whether you use the active class or not. You can verify this by using the computed css tab in inspect element(chrome).

The problem you are facing is caused by the fact that you are targeting the wrong class.
The solution however is to add the following code to your css:

```
.active {
        background-color: #E7E7E7;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g2jw1zp2/4/

**edit:**
To clarify this further to you, the need to add the background-color property arises from the fact that that .active class in bootstrap only targets the background color of the `<a>` elements in `<li>` tags instead of the `<li>` tag itself. You can see this for yourself in line 4032 of the bootstrap source code here:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: So, is the issue with the background of an active elements? It clearly has got some background but it is not filling the whole li element.

Comment: That is rather confusing, as it seems to work in the fiddle I shared. can you please check again?

Comment: So I am gathering the problem is with: background of .active element rather than padding...  But to be honest it doesn`t make sense why there is a colour that is not filling .li element from border to border. The solution works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add this line of css to your style:

```
.nav li.active {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
}
```

This will fix your issue.
Here is an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2jw1zp2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2jw1zp2/5/)**

Shows that its clearly a padding issue. For active `li` bootstrap adds some padding other than your padding which overrides yours. So you need not allow bootstrap to do that either you include your css after bootstrap or add a `!important` property like below.

```
.nav li a {
    padding: 15px 15px !important;
}
```

**Previous answer:**

```
.nav .active{
    padding: 0;
}
```

Will fix the issue. what I understood is there some some extra padding for bootstrap.min.css as below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: The padding remains the same on both the <li> and <a> whether you use the active class or not. You can verify this by using the computed css in inspect element.

Comment: @salmanxk please check screenshot its for computed CSS also check updates in the answer.

Comment: Yes, but the padding is not 'extra'. It was simply inherited from the original element otherwise adding the active class would have cause the element to expand, which does not happen in this scenario. Similarly my solution (which involves simply changing the background color of the active class) would not have worked had that been the case.